# Test firebase log event

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I am creating an android application.In that i have created some custom `events` in `firebase`. Now i need to test that event whether it is working or not. Is it possible to test the `events` without upload app to playstore?

Comment: Yes, just make sure to trigger those events when the application is running and then look at your firebase dashboard. It may take a while for the events to show up there.

Comment: but i am not able to see custom events n dashboard. Is it possible to do before uploading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable the [verbose logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/events?platform=android#view_events_in_the_android_studio_debug_log) and [debug mode](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview#enabling_debug_mode) in your app, then use the DebugView console. This way, you can verify if your analytics configuration and code implementation are correct.

To prevent your testing and development from affecting your measurements, events logged while in debug mode will be excluded from your overall Analytics data, and will not be included in your daily BigQuery export.